# Changing Menu Order on Collapsed Navbar in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a Bootstrap 3 Navbar that has two right-justified `<ul>` sections which gives me this:

[image]

When the menu is collapse for mobile, I get this:

[image]

I have two questions related to the collapsed menu.  1) How can I get the buttons to appear at the bottom of the collapsed menu instead of the top?  2) How can I change the styling of the buttons in the collapsed menu (without affecting the style in the horizontal menu)?

Below is the markup for this Navbar.  And yes I have a reason for having two separate `<ul>` sections:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">My Site</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn navbar-btn" id="Btn_1">Button One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn navbar-btn" id="Btn_2">Button Two</a></li>                    
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>                    
                    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
                </ul>                
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ended up finding a simpler solution for the reformatting and reordering of the button links on the collapsed navbar, one that doesn't require new javascript code:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                <li><a href="#" class="btn navbar-btn" id="Btn_1">Button One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="btn navbar-btn" id="Btn_2">Button Two</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-xs">
                <li><a href="#" >Button One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Button Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I simply duplicated the Button One and Button Two `<ul>` section and added it to the bottom.  I then removed the classes and ID on the `<a>` links so that no button formatting would occur.  Finally, I added the `hidden-xs` bootstrap class to the top `<ul>` and `visible-xs` to the bottom `<ul>` class.  That did the trick:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue but have been using Bootstrap 4.4 and this can be solved with a simple d-none d-block solution.

```html
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
      <li class="nav-item d-sm-none d-md-block">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-sm-none d-md-block">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Using this method allows for items 1 and 2 to only appear after the display is set to small and below. While also hiding the originals at that same display size.