# Change Order Of Navbar Header List Elements Without Change Order In Toggle Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I simply change the order of the navbar header list elements without changing the order in the toggle navigation menu. [Like this sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzhVW.png)

[image]

`My Code Is:`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid"> 
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inverseNavbar1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="inverseNavbar1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Though this may not be a great solution for you, this is somewhat of a duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875090/changing-menu-order-on-collapsed-navbar-in-bootstrap-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a good way to re-order the menu items. However, in your example you can add a `float: right` to Link1 when the screen is larger than 768px (Bootstrap's breakpoint for the mobile toggle menu).

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19693/)

```
<li class="float-right"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>

@media(min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav .float-right {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

**NOTE** - This solution is specific to your example. It would be tough using float to completely re-order all of your links.